# How to select clients who logged in each of last 3 months from current date?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have table in Oracle SQL like below:

```
ID    | last_logged
------|------------
123   | 2021-08-01
123   | 2021-07-01
123   | 2021-06-01
444   | 2021-04-02
444   | 2021-05-10
444   | 2021-05-11
...   | ...
```

ID - ID of client
last_logged - date of las login to system

And I need to select  ID of clients who logged in each of 3 last month. So I need as a result only:

```
ID
-----
123
```

Because currently we have September and this client logged in each of 3 last months: August, July, June.

How can I do that in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use aggregation with filtering:

```
select id
from t
where last_logged >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MON'), -3) and
      last_logged < trunc(sysdate, 'MON')
group by id
having count(distinct trunc(last_logged, 'MON')) = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Though there are many ways to achieve it, One of those methods are -

```
SELECT ID
  FROM your_table T1
 WHERE TO_CHAR(last_logged, 'MMYYYY') = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1), 'MMYYYY')
  AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                FROM your_table T2
               WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID
                 AND TO_CHAR(T2.last_logged, 'MMYYYY') = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2), 'MMYYYY'))
  AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                FROM your_table T3
               WHERE T1.ID = T3.ID
                 AND TO_CHAR(T3.last_logged, 'MMYYYY') = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -3), 'MMYYYY'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this solution.

```sql
With last_three_months (dt) as (
  select add_months(sysdate, -level) dt 
  from dual
  connect by level <= 3
)
select ID
from Your_Table t1
join last_three_months t2
on trunc(t1.last_logged, 'MONTH') = trunc(t2.dt, 'MONTH')
group by ID
having count(*) = 3
;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a7eceeacf20a687beac277be7954c915)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to keep a history of logins or are you looking for the last login date? If the latter and you are running 12c or higher you can get the information from the query below. You would just need your DBA to grant you access to the table or perhaps create a view and set permissions on that

```
select username, last_login
from sys.dba_users;
```